# Moving old passwords to new hashing algorithm?

Tags: security, passwords

I'm switching a site over to rails. It's quite a large site with 50k+ users. The problem is, the existing password hashing method is *extremely* weak. I have two options:

1) Switch to a new algorithm, generate random passwords for everyone and then email them those passwords and require the change immediately after

2) Implement new algorithm  but use the the old one before and then hash the result. For example:

Password: abcdef =Algorithm 1=> xj31ndn =Algorithm 2=> $21aafadsada214

Any new passwords would need to go through the original algorithm (md5) and then have the result of that hashed if that makes any sense? Is there any disadvantage to this?

Answer (score 24):

Normally it's not necessary to reset the passwords, one can just wait until the user logs in the next time.

1. First try to verify the entered password with the new algorithm. New passwords and already converted passwords will not take longer for verification then.
2. If it does not match, compare it with the old hash algorithm.
3. Should the old hash value match, then you can calculate and store the new hash, since you know the password then.

Every password-storing-system must have the option to switch to a better hash algorithm, your problem is not a one-time migration problem. Good password hash algorithms like BCrypt have a cost factor, from time to time you have to increase this cost factor (because of faster hardware), then you need the exact same procedure as you need for the migration.

Your option 2 with hashing the old hash is a good thing, if your first algorithm is really weak, and you want to give more protection immediately. In this case you can calculate a double-hash and replace the old hash in the database with the new double-hash.

```
$newHashToStoreInTheDb = new_hash($oldHashFromDb)
```

You should also mark this password-hash ([see why](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/103403/8343)), so you can recognize it as double-hash. This can be done in a separate database field, or you can include your own signature. Modern password hash functions also include a signature of the algorithm, so that they can upgrade to newer algorithms, and still can verify older hashes. The example shows the signature of a BCrypt hash:

```
$2y$10$nOUIs5kJ7naTuTFkBy1veuK0kSxUFXfuaOKdOKf9xYT0KKIGSJwFa
___
 |
 signature of hash-algorithm = 2y = BCrypt
```

The verification would run like this:

1. Decide whether it is a double-hash.
2. If it is a new hash, call the new hash-function to verify the entered password, and you are done.
3. If it is a double-hash, compare it with the double-hash algorithm `new_hash(old_hash($password))`.
4. Should the double-hash value match, then you can calculate and store the new hash.

Comment: In my opinion, double hashing is a horrible idea. One of the reasons that you hash a password, is that if if your hash is leaked, they can still not authenticate as a user.


If you do new_hash($raw_password) first, a user could log in by just entering the old leaked hash into the password field. Defeating the purpose of moving to a secure hashing algorithm.

Comment: @Lemon - Of course the old password-hash in the database would be replaced with the double hash, but you are right, that this is not the optimal solution. I edited the answer to show the best-practise, it still uses double-hashing, but marks the old hash.

Answer (score 10):

The simplest solution is probably to add a "password hash type" column to the database.  Set it initially to "old"; when a user logs in, re-hash the password using the new algorithm and set the database type to "new".

A variant of this method is to store the hash type as *part of* the hash string.  This works just as well, as long as you can unambiguously tell the different hash formats apart, and has the advantage that you can also include any other needed parameters (such as the [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) and the work factor for [key stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching)) in the same string without having to add extra fields for each to your database.

For example, this is the approach typically used by [modern Unix crypt(3) implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28Unix%29#Modular_crypt.283.29_Algorithms) (and the corresponding functions in various high-level languages like [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)): a classic DES-based (and horribly weak) password hash would look something like `abJnggxhB/yWI`, while a (slightly) more modern hash might look like `$1$z75qouSC$nNVPAk1FTd0yVd62S3sjR1`, where `1` specified the hashing method, `z75qouSC` is the salt and `nNVPAk1FTd0yVd62S3sjR1` the actual hash, and the delimiter `$` is chosen because it cannot appear in an old-style DES hash.

---

The method you suggest, where the new hashes are calculated as:

```
 hash = new_hash( old_hash( password ) )
```

*can* be useful in some cases, since it allows all existing records to be updated without having to wait for users to log in.  However, it's only safe if the old hash function preserves enough of the entropy in the passwords.

For example, even a fairly old and weak cryptographic hash function, like unsalted [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), would be good enough, since its output depends on the entire input and has up to 128 bits of entropy, which is more than almost any password will have (and more than enough to withstand a brute force attack, anyway).  On the other hand, trying to apply this construction using the old DES-based crypt(3) function as the old hash would be *disastrous*, since old crypt(3) would ignore all but the first 8 characters of each password (as well as the most significant bits of even those characters).

Comment: Just have to add that storing 'old' or 'new' as data values is a terrible idea. What comes after new? I once worked with a data model called 'NewModel', that was anything but. It was a source of constant confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new password field with all users that has updated their password with the new password method, and just update everybody with your option 2.

Combined this with forcing password update on login for all users with the old password method will automatically move all active users to the new password method.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be to keep both hashes available for the migration phase in separate columns of the database:

- If the new hash does not exist during login, check with the old hash and save the new hash and delete the old hash.
- If the new hash exists, use only this to verify.

Thus, after some time you will be left with the new hashes only - at least for those users who logged in at least one time.