# Is it possible to find out the character length of a MD5'd password?

Tags: php, hash, passwords

I have a hashed MD5 password saved in a MySQL database. Is there anyway to find out how many characters were in the original password?

I don't think there is because from what I've read it's difficult to decrypt a hashed password anyway.

Anyway I can do this?

EDIT: Because of the serious amount of backlash!! I'm not interested in decrypting a hash, because I know thats not a great idea from what I've read.

The reason I ask is because.

I am migrating an old system including historic database to a new updated application. All users, many thousands have their password saved in the database MD5, but most with less than 8 characters, so I just wanted to know if there was a way to know if their original password was over 8 characters, then I can bcrypt it or force users to change their password.

But I'll have to force all users to change their passwords by the looks of it

Comment: No - once the password is hashed it no longer exists in original form. However MD5 should **not** be used for password hashing (I'm looking at you Magento) - especially without salting it first.

Comment: It's *technically* possible, but you'd have to spend a lot of resources doing it (basically brute-force it) - `md5` is a "one-way" hash, so it cannot be decrypted. You should go away from using it though, `md5` is old and outdated - don't use it for storing passwords.

Comment: ***"Is there anyway to find out how many characters were in the original password?"*** - well, in order to do that, you would had to include a tiny piece of code that would have captured their original password, which I might add is not good etiquette.

Comment: @Qirel - actually it kind of isn't - you could get an MD5 collision with "badger" and the entire works of Shakespeare theoretically - there are far more possible permutations of strings than available MD5 values.

Comment: At this point, breaking MD5 is so easy that you might as well get decrypt the password itself and then figure out password length.

Comment: unfortunately there is no way to do that , cause `md5` is a one way hash password , and i suggest you to move to other hash algorithm other than md5 cause it's no longer recommended

Comment: OK, I get it. I can see people are pretty passionate about this not being possible!!. I didn't think it was, i was just purely asking to save forcing all users to ti change their passwords if their password was below a certain character limit

Comment: You could always try all possibilities till you hit one that matches that MD5

Comment: If there finite numbers of possible hashes, is it not so that one&thesame md5 hash can be generated from diff. inputs? `md5(md5(md5(md5())))` or?

Comment: You do not have to force folks to change. First of all, read this: Allow users to use the [passwords / phrases](https://xkcd.com/936/) they desire.

[Don't limit passwords.](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)

Comment: Now all you have to do is keep 2 columns, one for the old password hash, and one for the new. When a user logs in you check to see if the have a new hash. If they don't you would use their existing password to create a new hash with  PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: So it goes like this: user logs in with password, password is confirmed via `md5()`. If `md5()` version exists and newly hashed does not, add newly hashed to new column. If both exist, use the newly hashed column to authenticate user. Does that make sense?

Comment: In addition: if you insist they use a longer password/passphrase you can read the length of the original password when the user logs in, allow them to login (as above) and popup a message for them encouraging them to update their password with something longer.

Comment: @Eamonn could you please remove/retract your duplicate since it doesn't apply, thank you. People stand to close the question based on that which won't hold true to the real question.

Comment: I thought it was relevant as you can't measure the length of the string without decrypting the hash, but fair enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From OP's comment:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094885/is-it-possible-to-find-out-the-charater-length-of-a-password-md5d#comment71360468_42094885)

> *i was just purely asking to save forcing all users to ti change their passwords if their password was below a certain character limit – frobak*

The answer to this then is to use `strlen()`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

As for MD5, don't use it it's totally unsafe. A lot of water has gone under the bridge in over 30 years.

Use `password_hash()`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

As for decrypting a hash; it can't be done/reversed; that's why it's called a hash and not encrypted.

There are what's called "Rainbow tables":

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table

> *But I'll have to force all users to change their passwords by the looks of it*

Consult the following: [Converting md5 password hashes to PHP 5.5 password_hash()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906660/converting-md5-password-hashes-to-php-5-5-password-hash)

That way you can *"hit two posts with one stone"*.

However, [MD5 is 32-length](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php). You will need to increase that to 60+ in order to have the proper length when using [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and as Jay Blanchard stated in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094885/is-it-possible-to-find-out-the-character-length-of-a-md5d-password#comment71361341_42094885), otherwise that may fail "silently" later on when using [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: This is the correct answer, the only chance you'll get to measure the password length is when the user inputs it.

Comment: Ahhh. ok so i can do it this way. I can take user input and get string length, and then if entered password matches hashed pw I've got my answer. Thanks

Comment: @frobak again; [this comment I left you earlier...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094885/is-it-possible-to-find-out-the-character-length-of-a-md5d-password#comment71360138_42094885). However, there is no way for you to find out what their password lengths were from the beginning. You need to implement that method now; you can't go back in time, *as it were*, sorry.

Comment: @frobak Either that, ^ or force them to change their password and capture the length then and saved in another row. I wouldn't do that though but it's up to you and it can be done. P.s.: You're welcome.

Comment: Yeah new passwords length etc is fine using validation etc

Comment: @frobak Reload my answer, I added something near the bottom about md5 to password_hash().

Answer (score 3):

Nope. You can generate random strings and hash those until you find a match and measure the length of that (*this will take an extremely long time, and may actually be incorrect because of collisions, don't do it*), but outside of that, it's impossible.

Comment: You need to read the question again: Most particularly: *"Is there anyway to find out how many characters were in the original password?"*

Comment: The answer is still correct. I did read it.

Comment: this type of question's been asked many times before. Someone will post a duplicate soon. And that dv I noticed you just got, is not mine.

Comment: Yes - but because of collisions there's no way of knowing whether the match you've found **is** the original password.

Comment: Edited answer and flagged question as duplicate.

Comment: @Eamonn Actually, the real question after all was: *"i was just purely asking to save forcing all users to ti change their passwords if their password was below a certain character limit"* - as per [a comment they left under their question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094885/is-it-possible-to-find-out-the-charater-length-of-a-password-md5d#comment71360468_42094885).

Comment: Answer is still nope :)

Comment: The chance of collision is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already given and is worth upvoting, nevertheless I would like to share another view on the problem.

**Is it possible to find out the character length?**

No actually there is no way to tell the number of characters in the original password from a MD5 hash.

**Is it possible to find the passwords with less than 8 characters?**

Unfortunately *yes*. Since cracker tools can brute-force about [20 Giga Md5 per second](http://thepasswordproject.com/oclhashcat_benchmarking) it is possible to test all 7 character password combinations (a-z A-Z 0-9) in only 3 minutes!

Please note that this is *not* what I recommend to do, since it would be illegal, it is just to show how unsafe such hashes are. Instead you can calculate a second hash from the stored MD5 hash, I described this in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14402451/575765).