# Migrating users table with hashed password from old php app to new laravel app

Tags: php, hash, laravel, laravel-4

I am working on an old php app and the password of the users are hashed with the `md5()` function. So the passwords are stored like:

```
c0c92dd7cc524a1eb55ffeb8311dd73f
```

I am developing a new app with Laravel 4 and I need suggestions on how to migrate the `users` table without losing the password field.

Comment: Lose the password field.  You shouldn't continue to use md5, and there's no realistic way to reverse the md5 to plain text, just to rehash again with Laravel's bcrypt.  I would implement Laravel's password reset/reminder feature on your site, then do a foreach and set each users's password to a random one.  Then send an email to all your users asking them to reset their password.  Then you can completely use Laravel properly and securely.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Lose the password field as fast as you can, but if you don't want risking to lose users, you can do something like this on your auth method:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'))))
{
    return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
}
else
{
    $user = User::where('email', Input::get('email'))->first();

    if( $user && $user->password == md5(Input::get('password')) )
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

        $user->save();

        Auth::login($user->email);

        return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
    }

}
```

This will basically change a password from md5 to Hash every time a user logs in.

But you really have to think about sendind a link to all your users so they change their passwords.

**EDIT:**

To improve security even more, according to [@martinstoeckli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575765/martinstoeckli) comment, would be better to:

Hash all your current md5 passwords:

```
foreach(Users::all() as $user)
{
    $user->password = Hash::make($user->password);

    $user->save();
}
```

And then use an even more cleaner method to update your passwords:

```
$password = Input::get('password');
$email = Input::get('email');

if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password)))
{
    return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
}
else
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => md5($password))))
{
    Auth::user()->password = Hash::make($password);

    Auth::user()->save();

    return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
}
```

Comment: So basically retain old password hash and on first successful login rehash and update db? What would be the recommended retention period before phasing this out? Couldn't the old hash values be rehashed to the stronger algorithm and then the input double hashed (with some flag indicating when necessary?)

Comment: Yes. Still not really secure, but better than keep them forever on md5, since you cannot just convert them.

Comment: @Anthony - It is ok to hash the unsafe MD5 values with BCrypt, to give immediate protection. In this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14402451/575765) i tried to show the procedure. The biggest problem with MD5 is its speed, BCrypt will slow it down. Of course you should replace the hash after a successful login anyway.

Comment: Nice post and ideas about security. Just updated mine to add yours. Thanks.

Comment: Great logic as I was trying to do the same but rather than doing your way I was changing the complete system so that it takes only the md5 hash and decided to compromise security but with your solution I managed to save that hashing security +1 for this piece of code.