# Users are not able to login after Yii to Laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, yii, password-encryption

especially PHP team.  I have a scenario, see if anyone has some tips?

I have an old system developed on **Yii Framework**. The user table there has encrypted passwords.  I recently moved those **users** to our new system developed using **Laravel**.  However, we could not bring the passwords as they were encrypted.      Client wants to keep same login / password on the new system for all users. **Is it possible ?**

Comment: passwords are encypted using which technique?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rehashing passwords without asking all users to change them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987734/rehashing-passwords-without-asking-all-users-to-change-them)

Answer (score 0):

- Are you the developer?
- Are you using the same table and column and value for password?

I think you should be able to identify the hashing mechanism Yii used to store and verify passwords.

Let's imagine your Yii app used this for hashing passwords:

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPasswordHelper#hashPassword-detail

(You should check the old app's code and make sure what algorithm was used)

Then could try to modify your Login system in Laravel to use the same algorithm from Yii old app.

I'm not familiar with Laravel so I cannot say more on that but you should be able to customize it somehow.